# Mocha/Chai test returns error message and I couldnt find a way to test it

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

Title says it all and it returns a message like this
Error: startDate is a required field
I tried to use equal, instanceof.

```
describe('filter', () => {
      it('needs to return a startDate required message', async () => {
          let dto = {
            'endDate': '2000-02-02',
          };
          let result = await service.filter(dto);
          expect(result).to.throw();
        };
      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is you are not testing the error.

Think about that: When you are doing `expect(result).to.throw();` the error has been thrown.

Also `result` didn't throws any error.

So you can test the error is thrown when calling the function.

You can do it using [chai as promised](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-as-promised/) in this way:

```js
service.filter(dto).should.be.rejected;
```

Also, I've testd your approach using this code:

```js
describe('Test', () => {
  it('Test1', async () => {
    //Only this line pass the test
    thisFunctionThrowAnError().should.be.rejected;
    //This not pass
    let result = await thisFunctionThrowAnError();
    expect(result).to.throw();
  });
});

async function thisFunctionThrowAnError(){
  throw new Error("Can mocha get this error?")
}
```

Comment: should.be.rejected worked. I have also tried try/catch that works too!  thanks